# Get Text From file C#

Tags: c#

I am reading text file line By line and in that I want to get data between special characters after checking whether line containing special character or not.In my case I want to check whether line contains `<#Tag()>` and if it contains then fetch the string  between () i.e. line is having `<#Tag(param1)>` then it should return `param1`

But the problem is line may contains more then one `<#Tag()>`
For Example Line is having - `<#Tag(value1)> <#Tag(value2)>  <#Tag(value3)>`
Then it should return first `value1` then `value2` and then `value3`

```
string contents = File.ReadAllText(@"D:\Report Format.txt");
int start = contents.IndexOf("Header") + "Header".Length;
int end = contents.IndexOf("Data") - "Header".Length;
int length = end - start;
string headerData = contents.Substring(start, length);
headerData = headerData.Trim(' ', '-');
MessageBox.Show(headerData);
using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(headerData))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (line.Contains("<#Tag"))
        {
            string input = line;
            string output = input.Split('<', '>')[1];
            MessageBox.Show(output);
            Globals.Tags.SystemTagDateTime.Read();
            string newoutput =  Globals.Tags.SystemTagDateTime.Value.ToString();
            input = input.Replace(output, newoutput);
            input = Regex.Replace(input, "<", "");
            input = Regex.Replace(input, ">", "");
            MessageBox.Show(input);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried to use Regex ?

Comment: Please wait patiently for a regex guru to turn up and do this in one line.

Comment: And if it's likely to get more complex than this, you might be looking towards a parser, rather than trying to do this with string manipulation or regex.

Answer (score 3):

Try following

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(line, @"(?<=\<\#Tag\()\w+(?=\)\>)")
foreach (Match match in matches)
  MessageBox.Show(match.Value);
```

If you want to accomplish context described in comments try following.

```
  var line = "<#Tag(value1)> <#Tag(value2)>  <#Tag(value3)>";
  var matches = Regex.Matches(line, @"(?<=\<\#Tag\()\w+(?=\)\>)");
  //use matches in your case to find values. i assume 10, 20 , 30
  var values = new Dictionary<string, int>() { { "value1", 10 }, { "value2", 20 }, { "value3", 30 } };
  const string fullMatchRegexTemplate = @"\<\#Tag\({0}\)\>";
  foreach (var value in values)
    Regex.Replace(line, string.Format(fullMatchRegexTemplate, value.Key), value.Value.ToString());
```

Comment: This seems to get you started, but it only seems to match the first one in an online regex tester: https://regex101.com/

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth please add Global modifier.

Comment: Well would you look at that, fantastic.

Comment: It works but I also want to replace it by its value and place it in a string with same space as it was for example <#Tag(value1)> <#Tag(value2)>  <#Tag(value3)> then value1 value2 value3 (with same space as <#Tag(value1)> <#Tag(value2)>  <#Tag(value3)>) and then its value 10 20 30  (with same space as <#Tag(value1)> <#Tag(value2)>  <#Tag(value3)>)

Comment: @ParthDesai `Same space` you mean same width ?

Comment: no same emty space between two strings  <#Tag(value2)> empty space <#Tag(value3)>)

Comment: @ParthDesai Okey, but i did not understand second part of you question ` then its value 10 20 30 (with same space as <#Tag(value1)> <#Tag(value2)> <#Tag(value3)>)`, where 10, 20 and 30 comes from ?

Comment: value1 value2 value3 should then be replace by its value

Comment: @ParthDesai how do you get value of `value1` ?

Comment: Consider it as 10,20,30 In my case it comes from controller

Comment: @ParthDesai i will try.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a regex (I'll work on one)- but as a simple shortcut just do:

```
var tags  = line.Split(new string[] { "<#Tag" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
foreach(var tag in tags)
{
 //now parse each one
}
```

I see tchelidze just posted regex that looks pretty good so I'll defer to that answer as the regex one.

Comment: It works but I also want to replace it by its value and place it in a string with same space as it was for example <#Tag(value1)> <#Tag(value2)> <#Tag(value3)> then value1 value2 value3 (with same space as <#Tag(value1)> <#Tag(value2)> <#Tag(value3)>) and then its value 10 20 30 (with same space as <#Tag(value1)> <#Tag(value2)> <#Tag(value3)>)

Answer (score 0):

This might do the trick for you

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9]
```

Basically it matches all non-alphanumeric characters.

```
    private void removeTag()
    {
        string n = "<#Tag(value1)> <#Tag(value2)>  <#Tag(value3)>";
        string tmp = Regex.Replace(n, "Tag+", "");
        tmp = Regex.Replace(tmp, "[^0-9a-zA-Z]+", ",") ;
    }
```

Another one could be

```
string tmp = Regex.Replace(n, "[^0-9a-zA-Z]*[Tag]*[^0-9a-zA-Z]", ",");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also collect them after splitting the string by the constant values `<#Tag(` and `)>` like this:

```
string str = "<#Tag(value1)> <#Tag(value2)>  <#Tag(value3)>";
string[] values = str.Split(new string[] { "<#Tag(", ")>" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

values contains:

```
value1, value2, value3
```

Show the results in MessageBox:

```
foreach (string val in values) {
    if (!(String.IsNullOrEmpty(val.Trim()))) {
        MessageBox.Show(val);
    }
}
```

Edit based on you comment:

*Can i display complete value1 value2 value3 in one message box not with comma but with the same spacing as it was*

```
string text = "";
foreach (string val in values) {
    text += val;
}
MessageBox.Show(text);
```

Based on the comment:
*Now the last query Before showing it in message box I want to replace it by thier values for example 10 20 and 30*

```
string text = "";
foreach (string val in values) {
   // where val is matching your variable (let's assume you are using dictionary for storing the values)
   // else is white space or other... just add to text var.
   if (yourDictionary.ContainsKey(val)) {
       text += yourDictionary[val];
   } else {
       text += val;
   }
}
MessageBox.Show(text);
```

Comment: I want to popup 3 seperate message boxes for value1,value2,value3. It is dynamic it may be 4 or 5 or 1

Comment: I added code for showing the results in MessageBox.
This will work for 1, 3, 99 ... matches in your string.

Comment: Now it handles white spaces too.

Comment: Can i display complete value1 value2 value3 in one message box not with comma but with the same spacing as it was

Comment: Now the last query Before showing it in message box I want to replace it by thier values for example 10 20 and 30

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100952/discussion-between-parth-desai-and-ddan).